# Pyplot: changing color depending on class

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification

I have an array of values with their associated class labels (0 or 1). I'd like to change the colour of the plotted values based on their class labels. 
I'm using the matplotlib.pyplot plot function to plot the values:

```
plt.plot(data[0])
```

For each value the associated class labels are stored in an separate array of the same length as the data array.

The current plot looks like this:
[image]

The areas in between the red lines should be coloured differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it in two different data sets:

```
xx0 = class_labels == 0
xx1 = class_labels == 1

data_class_0 = data[0].copy()
data_class_0[xx1] = np.nan

data_class_1 = data[0].copy()
data_class_1[xx0] = np.nan

plt.plot(data_class_0, 'b')
plt.plot(data_class_1, 'r')
```